# How can I set a system's emission rate using Particle Designer 2.0?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d, particles

In cocos2d-iphone (2.1), `CCParticleSystem` has a property called `emissionRate`.

Is there any way to set it using Particle Designer 2.0? I've tried all the various settings but there doesn't seem to be anything achieving that effect. Perhaps I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emission rate is mainly a combination of Max Particles and their Lifespan.

If you change emissionRate in code and make it faster, what happens is that the emitter stops emitting particles for a while when it reaches "max particles" and will continue only when the "lifespan" of enough particles have reached so that the number of active particles falls below "max particles".

Comment: So there's no direct settings after all and I can just try to simulate it using those 2 settings. Thanks!